# Self-Tracking Entities with One to many relationship

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-3, self-tracking-entities

I Use Self-Tracking Entities with WCF to Work With data 
and asp.net MVC3 As a client 
any idea why this code doesn't work

in my MVC Controller i have this action to get User Contacts

```
      public ActionResult Contacts(int id)
      {
            var contacts = _proxy.GetContactsByUser(id);
            var mcontacts = Mapper.Map<Contact[], MContact[]>(contacts);

            return View(mcontacts);
      }
```

in WCF Service this is my method to get User contacts

```
      public List<Contact> GetContactsByUser(int id)
      {

                 var user = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserID == id);
                List<Contact> contacts = user.Contacts.ToList();
                return contacts;

      }
```

**my problem is `List<Contact> contacts` is Always null**

Answer (score 0):

what exactly doesn't work??

form the first look of it you have not created a map

```
 public ActionResult Contacts(int id)
      {
            var contacts = _proxy.GetContactsByUser(id);
            Mapper.CreateMap<Contact,MContact>();
            var mcontacts = Mapper.Map<Contact[], MContact[]>(contacts);

            return View(mcontacts);
      }
```

here is a useful link

http://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Lists%20and%20Arrays&referringTitle=Home

Comment: thanks @3nigma but i create a bootstrapper for mapper and i call it from  application start method. it is work for another methods

Comment: well you should have mentioned the bootstrapper, can you share the exact problem/error you are facing

Comment: my problem is the List<Contact> contacts is Always null

Comment: you must have checked that the contacts exist in the database against the specified `userid`?